# Remote desktop connection to server with TS and remote connection enabled

Tags: windows-server-2008, remote-desktop, rdp, terminal-server

I have a Server 2008 install with the Terminal Server role enabled, and Remote Desktop enabled.

If I try and connect to it with Remote Desktop Connection, how can I choose which sort of desktop I'm going to get (ie choose between the "real" server console and a faux Terminal Server one) ?

From what I'm seeing at the moment I'm always connecting to the console, so maybe I just haven't got TS set up right (but I'm curious to know how the choice would be exposed once it is working right, or what rules determine which sort of connection is established).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You will automatically be logging into the console if you are a member of the administrators group.

Comment: Thanks... yes creating a non-Admin user and using that did the trick.